# making a global variable and incrementing in function - CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, global-variables

I'm trying to make a global variable in my model to increment an id field in my mysql table, but CI won't allow me to make global variables.

I've searched around and people are mentioning having to create a library and declaring the global variable there, and then loading the library in the model and using the variable.

I understand that approach, but how/where would I be able to increment the variables value so that the next time it's called in a function it will be +1?

Thank you in advance for any help

edit: the thing I'm trying to do is whenever I insert a new row in a table, I want to continue on from the last entries id number i.e. last id number in the table is 9, I want to increment on from that number and make the new rows id number 10

Comment: please, somebody :P. still searching for a solution

Comment: You can use auto-increment in MYSQL. I don't see why would you this thing with PHP.

Comment: Yeah I figured I can do that, but I don't think I'm allowed to alter the way the database is setup

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to access the database through CI you can use the Active Record count_all() function.

From CI docs http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

> Permits you to determine the number of rows in a particular table.
>   Submit the table name in the first parameter. Example:
>
> `echo $this->db->count_all('my_table');`
>
> // Produces an integer, like 25

You would just get the number of rows in the table returned and add 1 for the row in your new entry.